# login Module getting error in yii

Tags: php, yii

I had tried simple login module in yii but I am getting error

Error message is following:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\yii_test\test\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php on line 658

Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumn() on a non-object in  
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\yii_test\test\framework\db\schema\CDbCommandBuilder.php on line 672
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

class User extends CActiveRecord
{

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return '{{user}}';
}

/**
 * Checks if the given password is correct.
 * @param string the password to be validated
 * @return boolean whether the password is valid
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($password,$this->password);
}

/**
 * Generates the password hash.
 * @param string password
 * @return string hash
 */
public function hashPassword($password)
{
    return CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add the login code?

Comment: What is your table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your table name. If you use a database `prefix` correct its name in your  `tableName`. If not, replace `{{user}}` with your table's exact name:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'YOUR TABLE NAME HERE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the code

```
     return parent::model($className);
```

has problem, but not for sure.

add

```
    Yii::log("SHOWMETYPE".gettype(parent::model($className)) ,error);
```

before

```
     return parent::model($className);
```

and check the type in error log.

Maybe the value of $className is invalid.

Comment: thanks for your answer bu i tried what you mention on you answer but  again also  getting error like Notice: Use of undefined constant error - assumed 'error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\yii_test\test\protected\models\User.php on line 11
CDbException

The table "{{user}}" for active record class "User" cannot be found in the database.

Comment: ya i got that problem is return '{{user}}'; i changed return 'user'; Thanks for your effort dude